# Running the program multiple times while keeping one process

Tags: c++, terminal, process, console

Perhaps it's a "I don't know about what i'm asking" question, so if i have to know something please let me know.

While running program with arguments or without (excluding program path/name argument) one process is launched. We can run program several times so several processes will be launched. And I'm searching for some way to keep one process while running program several times. Something like singleton. e.g.

In pseudocode:

```
...
bool tasksCompleted = false;
...
while !tasksCompleted{
    input = waitForNewInputFromConsole();
    launch_new_thread(HandleInput, input);
}
```

And in console:

```
>do_cool_stuff a b c - one process is launched, arguments a, b and c are passed, now HandleInput is handling them in new thread nad we're now wating for new input from console.
>do_cool_stuff x y - we have still one process, and x and y are passed, HandleInput is handling them in new thread, we're again waiting for more data.
```

If you know what i mean, and can help me with this one, please do so.

Thanks from advance,
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can rephrase the question. You have program Foo. Perhaps from the command line, someone says "Foo all the time". It launches program Foo.

Then the person says, "Foo me again", and it launches Foo a second time.

But instead, you don't want it to launch a second copy but somehow feed the arguments to the first program? If I understand what you're asking: you really can't.

What you COULD do is have Foo be really, really smart. The second copy would detect there's already a copy running and feed the data to it then exit. You could do this with shared memory, data shared by disk, or setting up a socket to try talking to. But your program would then need to ask itself if it's running and can take more data. Lots of work.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I want to do.. I will think of it, thanks.